# creating Subnet in a loop in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform. 
I am trying to create a code in which I can create the subnet in loop but cidrsubnet function is not working out as I don't want to change the subnet mask. 
For Example: I want to create the subnet with these IPs: Subnet 1: 10.90.46.0/27, subnet 2: 10.90.46.32/27 subnet3: 10.90.46.64/27 and so on till subnet 8: 10.90.46.224/27
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code, along with error messages you get?

Answer (score 4):

Apply a count, which will multiplicate the number of the resource.

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  default = "vpc-123"
}

#Here add all your 8 CIDR's to the list in "subnet_cidr" and for each one add one entry in "subnet_azs". You can repeat values in "subnet_azs" but not in subnet_cidr"

variable "subnet_cidr" {
  default = ["10.90.46.0/27", "10.90.46.32/27", "10.90.46.64/27", "10.90.46.224/27"]
}

variable "subnet_azs" {
  default = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c", "us-east-1c"]
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnets" {
  count             = 8
  vpc_id            = "${var.vpc_id}"
  cidr_block        = "${element(var.subnet_cidr, count.index)}"
  availability_zone = "${element(var.subnet_azs, count.index)}"
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome but is there anyway I can give the the First subnet 10.90.46.0/27 then it can create rest 8 subnet automatically without me mentioning all subnet CIDR. I am asking as in the other requirement I have work on is to create 16 subnet and I don't want to put the subnet manually.

Comment: Add to my answer this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnets.html :) if this solve your question, please mark as answer! @RohitSingh

Answer (score 2):

One way to automatically allocate a sequence of IP address ranges is to use [the `hashicorp/subnets/cidr` module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr) from the Terraform Registry:

```
module "subnet_addrs" {
  source  = "hashicorp/subnets/cidr"
  version = "1.0.0"

  base_cidr_block = "10.90.46.0/24"
  networks = [
    { name = "us-east-1a", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1b", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1c", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1d", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1e", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1f", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1g", new_bits = 3 },
    { name = "us-east-1h", new_bits = 3 },
  ]
}
```

With the above example, `module.subnet_addrs.network_cidr_blocks` will be a map like this:

```
{
  "us-east-1a" = "10.90.46.0/27"
  "us-east-1b" = "10.90.46.32/27"
  "us-east-1c" = "10.90.46.64/27"
  "us-east-1d" = "10.90.46.96/27"
  "us-east-1e" = "10.90.46.128/27"
  "us-east-1f" = "10.90.46.160/27"
  "us-east-1g" = "10.90.46.192/27"
  "us-east-1h" = "10.90.46.224/27"
}
```

A map like this can be used directly as the `for_each` of a resource, so we can then declare the subnets like this, using AWS an example (because you didn't say which cloud vendor you are using):

```
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnets" {
  for_each = module.subnet_addrs.network_cidr_blocks

  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  availability_zone = each.key
  cidr_block        = each.value
}
```

There's some guidance in the readme of this module about [things to keep in mind if you intend to [rename or renumber networks later](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr/1.0.0#changing-networks-later), to ensure that the changes you make are compatible with objects that already exist. I'd suggest reviewing that documentation before taking this path to make sure that you'd be able to apply any future changes to your network topology you might imagine making in the future.

For example, the allocations in the above example already cover the entire addressing space `"10.90.46.0/24"`, so if you wanted to add a new subnet in future without introducing any new addressing space you'd need to replace one of those existing subnets with a pair of replacement subnets that both have `new_bits = 4` and thus a prefix length of `/28` instead of `/27`, so that you'd have one additional bit available for network numbering.